# What does putting quotes around $@ in bash script do? i.e. "$@" instead of $@

Tags: bash

I was getting errors passing in a command and when I put quotes around that things worked just fine.  Just curious how that works.

Comment: Quote all the variables until it does not work as expected, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes around $@ (and similarly, ${array[@]}) prevents globbing and word splitting of individual elements, while still expanding to multiple separate arguments.

See: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2068